# how adddependency method works in NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

i am testing NSoperationqueue

```
 queue = NSOperationQueue()
    let operation1 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
        let img1 = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.img1)
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
            self.imgs1.image = UIImage(data: img1!)

        })
    })

    operation1.completionBlock = {
        print("Operation 1 completed")
    }
    queue.addOperation(operation1)




    let operation2 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
        let img2 = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.img2)
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
            self.imgs2.image = UIImage(data: img2!)

        })
    })



    operation2.completionBlock = {
        print("Operation 2 completed")
    }
    queue.addOperation(operation2)

    let operation3 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
        let img3 = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.img3)
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
            self.imgs3.image = UIImage(data: img3!)

        })
    })

    operation3.completionBlock = {
        print("Operation 3 completed")
    }
    queue.addOperation(operation3)

 operation3.addDependency(operation1)

}
```

the result is

> Operation 3 completed
>
> Operation 1 completed
>
> Operation 2 completed

can you please explain addDependency works

it should work like operation 1 should complete first ?

how to execute one after other ?

how to create dependency ?

Comment: You have your print statements inside of the completion block. The addDependency will only apply to the BlockOperation not the completion block, move your print statements to this area and it will make more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use it :

```
operation3.addDependency(operation2)
operation2.addDependency(operation1)
```

operation3 will start when operation2 be completed and operation2 will start when operation1 be completed .

notice : operation1 should be completed until operation2 will start

```
queue = NSOperationQueue()
    let operation1 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
        let img1 = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.img1)
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
            self.imgs1.image = UIImage(data: img1!)

        })
    })

    operation1.completionBlock = {
        print("Operation 1 completed")
    }


    let operation2 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
        let img2 = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.img2)
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
            self.imgs2.image = UIImage(data: img2!)

        })
    })



    operation2.completionBlock = {
        print("Operation 2 completed")
    }

    let operation3 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
        let img3 = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.img3)
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
            self.imgs3.image = UIImage(data: img3!)

        })
    })

    operation3.completionBlock = {
        print("Operation 3 completed")
    }

    operation3.addDependency(operation2)
    operation2.addDependency(operation1)

    queue.addOperation(operation1)
    queue.addOperation(operation2)
    queue.addOperation(operation3)


}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Hi first try creating all the operations, and then add the
   dependency and then add them to the queue, like given below.

   create operation1 then operation2 then operation3

   After that  do - operation3.addDependency(operation1)

   then add the operations to the queue, 
   queue.addOperation(operation1) queue.addOperation(operation2)
   queue.addOperation(operation3)

Answer (score 0):

```
  queue = NSOperationQueue()
    let operation1 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
        let img1 = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.img1)
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
            self.imgs1.image = UIImage(data: img1!)

        })
    })

    operation1.completionBlock = {
        print("Operation 1 completed")
    }
    queue.addOperation(operation1)




    let operation2 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
        let img2 = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.img2)
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
            self.imgs2.image = UIImage(data: img2!)

        })
    })



    operation2.completionBlock = {
        print("Operation 2 completed")
    }
    queue.addOperation(operation2)

    let operation3 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
        let img3 = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.img3)
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
            self.imgs3.image = UIImage(data: img3!)

        })
    })

    operation3.completionBlock = {
        print("Operation 3 completed")
    }
    queue.addOperation(operation3)

    operation2.addDependency(operation1)
    operation3.addDependency(operation2)
  }
```

- Operation 2 is dependent on operation 1 (means operation 2 will start
  once after operation 1 completed)
- Operation 3 will start executing after operation 2 complete.

### Note: If any other other operation is there then let op4 can be start before 1,2,3

Output:

---

Operation 1 completed

Operation 2 completed

Operation 3 completed

Answer (score -1):

`NSOperationQueue` dependency only works when you are using `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()`.

Consider you have to perform 2 NSOperation, one is to download image and second apply filter. In this case applying filter is dependent on download operation. Following code show dependency operation.

```
// *** create image download operation ***
let imageOperation: NSOperation = ...

// *** create filter operation ***
let filterOperation: NSOperation = ...

// *** Add dependency of filter operation on image download operation ***
filterOperation.addDependency(imageOperation)

// *** Init NSOperationQueue mainQueue ***
let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()

// *** Add Operations to queue ***
operationQueue.addOperations([imageOperation, filterOperation], waitUntilFinished: false)
```

Referenced from [**NSHipter** blog](http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/)

Comment: Dependancies work with your self-created queues as well as the main queue.